# Meteor observer with two different applications

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactive-programming

Because changed data (inserted by application A) needs to be displayed in application B in realtime we decided to go with `.find().observe(...)`.

It does look like:

```
App A   ->    Insert   ->   mongodb    <- observe  -> publish   -> Display App B
```

This works fine but it has a delay of about 3-5 seconds between Inserting in A and displaying in B. How can i change this?

Initially i thought, Oplog-Observe-Driver is default in Meteor > Version 1 and does react in realtime. Does it still POLL or is there some other reason for the delay????

Thanks for your expanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Oplog, then the changes will be immediate. If you're using poll then it'll take a few seconds as you wrote.
You need to set MONGO_OPLOG_URL correctly to make this work. (And of course your MongoDB needs to be Oplog enabled.)

Also, you don't need to use `find().observe()` if you're in a reactive context, `find()` is enough. On the server though you might need `find().observe()` depending on what you're doing.

Comment: This sounds like a solution. How can i set the OPLOG_URL and enable Oplog?

Comment: this is the solution. have a look at this: https://meteorhacks.com/mongodb-oplog-and-meteor:
`MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://user:pass@host1:port,host2:port,host3:port/local`

Comment: or possibly this: https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-10-set-up-oplog-tailing-on-ubuntu/17

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `DDP.connect`? You also have to use the `onReconnect`

```
Remote = DDP.connect('http://yourremoteserver');
MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('same_name', Remote);

// do whatever you need with collection

let watchCollection = function (query={}, project={}) {
  return MyCollection.find(query, project).observe({
    changed: function () { console.log('Something changed!') }
  });
}
DDP.onReconnect(watchCollection);
```